# How to connect to URL WITHOUT opening browser or using browserfield in Blackberry

Tags: java, url, blackberry, httprequest

I am trying to send information to my company's server. Basically when I enter a URL pointing to it and connect to it in a browser, it takes parameters contained in the URL and puts them in a database. Again when done in a browser, it works. However, I would like to be able to send this information every time an event of importance (like scanning a qr code in our app) happens, and I want it to be done in the background (without the user knowing.)

We have tried ConnectionFactory, HTTPRequests etc etc, nothing has worked for us so far.

I am sure there is a simple way to go about this.

Can anyone provide us with the few elusive lines of code to help us do what we want to do??

Thanks alot!

Edit:

Okay here is some code we tried using (one of many code snippets) but it did not work:

```
public class ConnectionThread extends Thread{
String URL;       
public ConnectionThread(String URL) {     

         this.URL = URL;
}       
public void run() {

    ServerCalls sc = new ServerCalls(); // This is for generating the URL
    ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
    ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
    connDesc = connFact.getConnection(sc.fillParameters(URL));

    if (connDesc != null)
    {
        HttpConnection httpConn;
        httpConn = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
    }
    }
}
```

and we call
    new ConnectionThread(barcode).start()

when we need it to send the info to the server.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  Please show some code.  Have you tried using `HttpConnection` yet?

Comment: Have you tried using `javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(URL)` to get an `HttpConnection`?

Answer (score 1):

For opening the url you can use

`javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection` Package.

And here is the code how to go about that....

```
HttpConnection connection=(HttpConnection) Connector.open(your url+";deviceside=true");
if(connection.getResponseCode()==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
       write your code, Which you want to get from url or any thing you want

    }else{
      UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
      Dialog.inform("connection error");
      }
   });
}
```

This may help you :)

Comment: Unfortunately it catches an IOException on this line:
HttpConnection connection=(HttpConnection) Connector.open(your url+";deviceside=true");

Comment: The following point may help: "IOException - if the firewall disallows a connection that is not btspp or comm."